# Is it possible to create an ENUM of smallints in postgres 11.x?

Tags: sql, postgresql, enums, postgresql-11

I'd like to create an enum TYPE to constrain a pl/pgsql function to accept an argument that's 1, 2, or 3.  Enum types seemed like the way to go about this.

I've tried creating my enum as below:

```
CREATE TYPE my_enum AS ENUM ('1'::smallint, '2'::smallint);
/*                           ^ syntax error here         */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html), an `ENUM` type is always going to be a fixed value:

> An enum value occupies four bytes on disk. The length of an enum value's textual label is limited by the `NAMEDATALEN` setting compiled into PostgreSQL; in standard builds this means at most 63 bytes.

Therefore, you can't cast it into a `smallint` -- sorry!

Instead, I suppose you can create a reference table and create a foreign key constraint, if space is your concern.

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://www.enterprisedb.com)

Comment: 4 bytes!? in what situation would you need to support 4.2 billion enum values? i've never even seen a mysql database max out mysql's 2-byte enums (for a max of 65534+null values)

Comment: It's not because number of values needed. The data type for enum is REAL. Thus 4 bytes. By using reals Postgres can "... [adds a new value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-altertype.html) to an enum type. The new value's place in the enum's ordering can be specified as being BEFORE or AFTER one of the existing values"